# I need help to optimize my database schema

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

I've done a simple database schema but I'm not proud of it and I think that I can optimize it.
If someone can help me, or give me some advices !

[image]

Comment: This is a schema. It's relational. What's the problem here?

Comment: One thing that strikes me as odd is postal codes are not associated with regions, cities or countries, which is sort of what they're all about. I'm not sure why postal code needs its own first-class record if you're not going to treat it as linked to things like this. Just use a dumb string field instead.

Comment: What's the purpose? Seems unnecessary for the names to be unique (pk guarantees uniqueness) and you may want to have multiple lines for the addresses

Comment: @tadman Oh yes you're right, it's lack of attention. Currently, postal_code FK is in city and university.

Comment: @mjlitz Like addiing multiple column like : address1 address2 address3  ?

Comment: Something like that. Typically address fields have at least 2 lines. Could do something like address_line_1 and address_line_2

Comment: @tadman Oh okay, I understand your comment. Yes you're right, I don't need to create a class for postal_code. But what do you mean by : "just use dumb string field". What does that mean please ?

Comment: I mean use `VARCHAR(255)` instead of a whole on record with indexes and everything. Who needs that unless there's something specific about that postal code data you need to focus on. It's also probably useless as any university of consequence will be big enough to have multiple postal codes and that geographic information may as well be put into the university record itself.

Comment: Show us the main `SELECTs`, _then_ we can critique it more.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `TEXT` for `name` unless you have some really long names.  Instead use a reasonably limited `VARCHAR`.

Why use a 4-byte int for country_code, when there are standard 2-byte (`CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii`) country codes.

If you are using MySQL, check the syntax for the spatial stuff.

`has_regions` will give you a lot of grief.  Other than storing and later displaying city, region, country, what are the tables for?